# Pandas DataFrame Index length doesn't match number of rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a DataFrame with a two levels MultiIndex: 'State' and 'RegionName' (if anyone's completed the Applied Data Science for Python specialization on Coursera, it's the final project of the first class).

I'm trying to make the 'RegionName' level of the index into a column of the DataFrame and use it in order to create a boolean mask.

I tried following:

```
housing_data['Town'] = housing_data.index.levels[1]
```

And I get the error: "Length of values does not match length of index"

I'm trying to figure out how that's possible because I'm literally using the index of the DataFrame to add a column to the same DataFrame. How can the lengths not match?

If it adds any extra insight:

```
np.shape(housing_data) returns (10730, 69)

len(housing_data.index) returns 10730

yet somehow len(housing_data.index.levels[1]) returns 8258
```

Could that be part of my problem?

Comment: Perhaps just do a reset_index() on this df (or its copy) to get hold of the series containing level 1 part of the multiindex. This will return this series with duplicates which should match the length of your full df.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR; skip to the last part (no need to create a new column for boolean masking in the first place!)

Now, to actually answer your question ...

There's nothing wrong with your DataFrame! With your approach, you are only missing one step. Getting the values from `.levels[]` is just the first step.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

iterables = [['bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'qux'], ['one', 'two']]
mult_index  = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables, names=['first', 'second'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 3), index=mult_index, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

mult_index # same as df.index
```

This will output:

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'qux'], ['one', 'two']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]],
           names=['first', 'second'])
```

From here, you see that you will returning the `levels` values is not enough. You must also map those values onto the appropriate `labels` values. The length of `labels` will be the same as the number of rows.

```
df['index_val1'] = [ mult_index.levels[0][i] for i in mult_index.labels[0]]
```

or

```
df['index_val1'] = [ df.index.levels[0][i] for i in df.index.labels[0]]
```

There is a built-in function for this mapping though!

```
df['index_val1'] = df.index.get_level_values(0)
```

You can actually, just use `get_level_values` to do all of your boolean masking. *There's no need to create the additional column*.

```
df[ df.index.get_level_values(0)=='bar']
```

Comment: Thanks, get_level_values is exactly what I was looking for! And thanks for explaining the structure of accessing a the multi-index.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reset?

```
df.reset_index(level=['RegionName'],inplace=True)
```